# Using a Coroutine in a loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a question about coroutines in a loop. More specific about how I can achieve it that my loop continues to check the condition until the waitForSeconds in the coroutine are over.

I have attached a screenshot of my code. My problem is that the Line "Now I am executed" is shown right after myAudio.Play();
It makes sense since the coroutine only waits for the statements after the yield return but how can I make it work with the for loop?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: and the answer would be: Make the loop itself to be in a Coroutine and then instead of `StartCoroutine(PlayAndWait(x))` use `yield return PlayAndWait(x)`

Comment: Oh I am sorry for uploading the picture. I didn't know that but thanks a lot  for telling me!

Comment: And thank you so much for your answer!! That finally worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) starts each `IEnumerator`as a new Coroutine and immediately continuous with the rest of the code.

So as said without having further context of your code  what you would do is something like

```
private void playDBStack()
{
    fillList();

    StartCoroutine(playDBStackRoutine())
}

private IEnumerator playDBStackRoutine()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        // executes playAudio and waits for it to finish
        yield return playAudio();
    }
}

private IEnumerator playAudio()
{
    var x = chooseList(score);
    // executes PlayAndWait and wait for it to finish
    yield return PlayAndWait(x);
}
```

this way you execute and at the same time wait until the `IEnumerator`s are finished before going to the next one.

---

Some further notes:

- The line

  ```
   myAudio.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
  ```

  does absolutely nothing.
- The entire method `updateScore` in its current state could simply be replaced by using

  ```
   score++;
  ```

  I would consider a method that can be replaced by a simple operator "code smell" ;)